# DecisionTreeClassifier: associating names to labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am using sklearn's [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.fit); it is said that the class labels can be of type `str`.

When I plot the decision tree using [sklearn.tree.plot_tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html), I can specify the `class_names`, which the docs says should be "Names of each of the target classes in ascending numerical order." But what about for `str` classes/labels? Is it the lexicographical order then?

Answer (score 1):

For converting string labels `str` to  Numeric you can use sklearn `LabelEncoder`

LabelEncoder Encode target labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1.

Example:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y = ["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"]
y_encode = le.fit_transform(y)
y_encode
```

output:

```
array([1, 1, 2, 0])
```

For more details visit the [`LabelEncoder` docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

Comment: This is an interesting indirect approach - instead of using `str` labels at all, we convert to `int`s, so there is no confusion.